# How can I send data after Preview in React JS with axios?

Tags: reactjs, axios

I trying to create multiple send data button. Button work fine in last step display Preview and user send data. In last step data isn't in form body. How can I send this data after submit user?

```js
    function ShowOrNot(props) {
        const [showForm, setShowForm] = useState(false);
        const [showPreview, setShowPreview] = useState(false);
        const [formHidden, setFormHidden] = useState(false);
        const [inputs , setInputs] = useState({
            videoTitle: "",
            videoCategory: "",
            videoSummary: "",
            videoText: "",
            coverVideo: null,
            videoPoster: null,
            file: null,
        })
        const sendForm = (e) => {
            e.preventDefault();
            const formData = new FormData(e.target);
            formData.append("filename",videoData);
            formData.append("videoPoster", posterData);
            formData.append("coverVideo", imgData);
            formData.append("videoSummary", inputs?.videoSummary);
            formData.append("videoText", inputs?.videoText);
            formData.append("videoTitle", inputs?.videoTitle);
            formData.append("videoCategory",               inputs?.videoCategory);
            const config = {
                headers: {
                    "content-type": "multipart/form-data",
                    email: props.user.email,
                },
            };
            axios
                .post(
                    "http://localhost:5000/api/momayezi/uploadFiles/upload",
                    formData,
                    config
                )
                .then((response) => {
                    alert("The file is successfully uploaded");
                })
                .catch((error) => {
                    console.log(error);
                });
        }

        const onChange = ({ target }) => {
            const value = target?.value;
            const name = target?.name;
            setInputs({
                ...inputs,
                [name] : value
            });
        };
        const [picture, setPicture] = useState(null);
        const [imgData, setImgData] = useState(null);
        const onChangePicture = e => {
            if (e.target.files[0]) {
                setPicture(e.target.files[0]);
                const reader = new FileReader();
                reader.addEventListener("load", () => {
                    setImgData(reader.result);
                });
                reader.readAsDataURL(e.target.files[0]);
            }
        };
        const [poster, setPoster] = useState(null);
        const [posterData, setPosterData] = useState(null);
        const onChangePoster = e => {
            if (e.target.files[0]) {
                setPoster(e.target.files[0]);
                const reader = new FileReader();
                reader.addEventListener("load", () => {
                    setPosterData(reader.result);
                });
                reader.readAsDataURL(e.target.files[0]);
            }
        };
        const [video, setVideo] = useState(null);
        const [videoData, setVideoData] = useState(null);
        const onChangeVideo = e => {
            if (e.target.files[0]) {
                setVideo(e.target.files[0]);
                const reader = new FileReader();
                reader.addEventListener("load", () => {
                    setVideoData(reader.result);
                });
                reader.readAsDataURL(e.target.files[0]);
            }
        };
        return (
            <div className="col-12">
                {!showForm ? (
                    <ShowFormButton onClick={() => setShowForm(true)}/>
                ) : undefined}

                {showForm ? (
                    <div className={''} id="scrollbar-style">
                        <div>
                            <HideFormButton
                                onClick={() => {
                                    setShowForm(false);
                                }}
                            />
                        </div>
                        {!formHidden ?
                           
                                <form
                                    onSubmit={ (e) => e.preventDefault()}
                                    className={'mt-3 content-send-form-data register-teacher-inputs-box '}>
                                    <Row>
                                        <div className={'col-lg-6 col-12 mt-4'}>
                                            <label htmlFor={'videoTitle'} className={' text-right'}>
                                                <span>*</span>
                                            </label>
                                            <input
                                                type="text"
                                                className="form-control"
                                                placeholder={'videoTitle'}
                                                name={'videoTitle'}
                                                required="true"
                                                onChange={onChange}
                                                onBlur={(e) => (e.target.placeholder = 'videoTitle')}
                                                onFocus={(e) => (e.target.placeholder = '')}
                                            />
                                        </div>
                                        <div className={'col-lg-6 col-12 mt-4'}>
                                            <label htmlFor={'videoCategory'} className={' text-right'}>
                                                <span>*</span>
                                            </label>
                                            <input
                                                type="text"
                                                className="form-control"
                                                placeholder={'دvideoCategory'}
                                                name={'videoCategory'}
                                                onChange={onChange}
                                                required="true"
                                                onBlur={(e) => (e.target.placeholder = 'videoCategory')}
                                                onFocus={(e) => (e.target.placeholder = '')}
                                            />
                                        </div>
                                    </Row>
                                    <Row>
                                        <div className="col-12 mt-3">
                                            <label htmlFor={'name'} className={'label-full-size text-right'}>
                                                <span>*</span>
                                            </label>
                                            <input
                                                type="text"
                                                className="form-control"
                                                placeholder={'خلاصه videoSummary'}
                                                name={'videoSummary'}
                                                required="true"
                                                onChange={onChange}
                                                onBlur={(e) => (e.target.placeholder = 'خلاصه videoSummary')}
                                                onFocus={(e) => (e.target.placeholder = '')}
                                            />
                                        </div>
                                    </Row>
                                    <Row>
                                        <div className="col-12 mt-3">
                                            <label
                                                htmlFor={'name'}
                                                className={'label-full-size text-right textarea-label'}
                                            >
                                                <span>*</span>
                                            </label>
                                            <textarea
                                                className="video-text-form form-control"
                                                placeholder={'متن videoText'}
                                                name={'videoText'}
                                                required="true"
                                                onChange={onChange}
                                                onBlur={(e) => (e.target.placeholder = 'متن videoText')}
                                                onFocus={(e) => (e.target.placeholder = '')}
                                            />
                                        </div>
                                    </Row>
                                    <Row>
                                        <div className="col-12 mt-3 video-upload-input-btn">
                                            <div className="register_wrapper">
                                                <div className="register_player_column_layout_one">
                                                    <div className="register_player_Twocolumn_layout_two">
                                                        <form className="myForm">
                                                            <div className="formInstructionsDiv formElement">
                                                                <p className="instructionsText" />
                                                                <div className="register_profile_image">
                                                                    <input
                                                                        accept={"video/*"}
                                                                        id="videoTeacher"
                                                                        type="file"
                                                                        onChange={onChangeVideo}
                                                                        name={"filename"}
                                                                    />
                                                                </div>
                                                            </div>
                                                        </form>
                                                    </div>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>

                                        </div>
                                    </Row>
                                    <Row>
                                        <div className="col-lg-6 col-12 mt-3">
                                            <div className="register_wrapper">
                                                <div className="register_player_column_layout_one">
                                                    <div className="register_player_Twocolumn_layout_two">
                                                        <form className="myForm">
                                                            <div className="formInstructionsDiv formElement">
                                                                <p className="instructionsText" />
                                                                <div className="register_profile_image">
                                                                    <input name={"videoPoster"} accept={"image/*"} id="posterPicture" type="file" onChange={onChangePoster} />
                                                                </div>

                                                            </div>
                                                        </form>
                                                    </div>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                        <div className="col-lg-6 col-12 mt-3">
                                            <div className="register_wrapper">
                                                <div className="register_player_column_layout_one">
                                                    <div className="register_player_Twocolumn_layout_two">
                                                        <form className="myForm">
                                                            <div className="formInstructionsDiv formElement">
                                                                <p className="instructionsText" />
                                                                <div className="register_profile_image">
                                                                    <input
                                                                        name={"coverVideo"}
                                                                        accept={"image/*"}
                                                                        id="profilePic"
                                                                        type="file"
                                                                        onChange={onChangePicture}
                                                                    />
                                                                </div>

                                                            </div>
                                                        </form>
                                                    </div>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </Row>
                                </form>
                                
                            </div>
                            : undefined}

                        {!showPreview ? (
                            <ShowPreviewButton
                                onClick={() => {
                                    setShowPreview(true);
                                    setFormHidden(true);
                                }}
                            />
                        ) : undefined}
                        {showPreview ? (
                            <div className={"preview-send-wrapper"}>
                               <form onSubmit={(e) => sendForm(e)}
                                <div className={"mt-5 preview-send-cover"}>
                                    <img className="playerProfilePic_home_tile" src={imgData} />
                                </div>
                                <div className={"preview-send-video-poster"}>
                                   <video poster={posterData} controls>
                                       <source src={videoData}/>
                                   </video>
                                    <h1 className={"mt-4"}>
                                        {inputs?.videoTitle}
                                        <span className={"mr-4"}><p>{inputs?.videoCategory}</p></span>
                                    </h1>
                                    <h4 className={"mt-3"}>
                                        {inputs?.videoSummary}
                                    </h4>
                                </div>
                                <div className={"preview-send-summary-video"}>
                                    <p>
                                        {inputs?.videoText}
                                    </p>
                                </div>
                                <Row>
                                    <div className={"col-lg-8 col-12"}>
                                        <button onSubmit={sendForm} type={"submit"} className={"send-video-btn-final"}>
                                            Send
                                        </button>
                                    </div>
                                    <div className={"col-lg-4 col-12"}>
                                        <SendButton
                                            onClick={() => {
                                                setFormHidden(false);
                                                setShowPreview(false);
                                                setShowForm(true);
                                            }}
                                        />
                                    </div>
                                </Row>
</form>
                            </div>
                        ) : undefined}
                    </div>
                ) : undefined}
            </div>
        );
    }

    function SendButton({onClick}) {
        return (
            <div>
                <button className="edit-send-video-btn" onClick={onClick}>
                    Edit
                </button>
            </div>
        );
    }

    function ShowFormButton({onClick}) {
        return (
            <div>
                <button className="upload-content-btn w-100" onClick={onClick}>
                    <span className="ml-2">
                     
                    </span>Upload{' '}
                </button>
            </div>
        );
    }

    function ShowPreviewButton({onClick}) {
      
        return (
            <div className={"row show-preview-button"}>
                <div className="col-lg-8 col mt-3">
                    <button className="preview-send-data-btn" onClick={onClick}>
                       Preview
                    </button>
                </div>
                <div className="col-lg-4 col mt-3">
                    <button className="draft-send-data-btn">Draft</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        );
    }

    function HideFormButton({onClick}) {
        return (
            <div className={'content-send-form-close-btn'}>
                <button onClick={onClick} className={'close-modal-btn'}>
                    <span>Close</span>
                  
                </button>
            </div>
        );
    }

    ReactDOM.render(<ShowOrNot/>, document.getElementById('root'));

    class UploadContentButton extends Component {
        componentDidMount() {
            store.dispatch(loadUser())
        }
        static propTypes = {
            isAuthenticated : PropTypes.bool,
            auth: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
            logout: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
        };

        render() {
            return (
                <div className="mt-5">
                    <div className={"row"} id="show-button">
                        <ShowOrNot/>
                    </div>
                </div>
            );
        }

    }
    const mapStateToProps = (state) => ({
        setPass: state.auth.setPass,
        isAuthenticated: state.auth.isAuthenticated,
        error: state.error,
        auth: state.auth,
        user: state.auth.user,
    });
    export default connect(mapStateToProps, {loadUser}) (UploadContentButton)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

After create Preview section I test endpoint and it's work fine, Now when submit Send button no response back to me.
How to when submit Send button data Posted to server?

Answer (score 0):

Either put your data in local storage or use state management.

for state management react-redux is a package which you can install by below command.

```
npm i react-redux
```

Comment: I using react redux now and I see state in hooks but no response from server when submitted.

Comment: Did your request was successful? Did you got any errors? Was their no response at all or some error?

Comment: No error No success, nothing.  but when in trying to by form submit it's work fine and have response.

Comment: So was your request successful, i mean can you see the request in your developer console being made?

Comment: Now I have this error : `TypeError: Failed to construct 'FormData': parameter 1 is not of type 'HTMLFormElement'.
`.

Comment: FormData expects a form element, not a string.  check that.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/235723/discussion-between-kup-and-sajjad-shiasi).

Comment: Created `form` tag and push all code inside that, Now I have response. also I have this error : `×
TypeError: Cannot read property 'preventDefault' of undefined`